# How to get display width and height using the nokia sdk?

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, screen, nokia

I can't seem to find any place where it is described how i can get the display width and height, using nokia sdk and QT.

I need to resize my GUI when i have detected the screensize.

Or do anyone else have a better solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the display size with [`QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry).

Comment: it's probably right, but when i try this at my main window:  "ui->setupUi(this);
    QRect screenSize = QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(*parent);"   i get "cannot call memeber function 'const QRect QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(const QWidget*) const' without object

Comment: It's not a static function. You need to get an instance by calling QApplication::desktop() http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qapplication.html#desktop